# How to count string numbers row-wisely and count percentage (only not empty columns taking into account)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

For the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(test = c("A", "B", "C"), `2019` = c("true", "", 
"false"), `2020` = c("false", "true", "true"), `2021` = c("true", 
"false", "true"), `2022` = c("", "false", "false")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Out:

```
  test  2019  2020  2021  2022
1    A  true false  true      
2    B        true false false
3    C false  true  true false
```

I need to count number of `true`s from column `2019` to `2022`, then calculate percentage of number of `true` from **not NA or not empty values**:

The expected result could be like this:

```
  test  2019  2020  2021  2022 true_pct
1    A  true false  true           0.67 # 2/3
2    B        true false false     0.33 # 1/3
3    C false  true  true false     0.50 # 2/4
```

The code below returns wrong answer since it take all year columns since there are empty string in the data, but I need to filter mask such as `!is.na(df[,2:5]) | df[,2:5] != ''`:

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[-1] == "true")
df$not_na <- rowSums(!is.na(df[,2:5]))
# df$not_na <- rowSums(!complete.cases(df[,2:5]))
df$true_pct <- df$count/df$not_na
```

Out:

```
  test  2019  2020  2021  2022 count not_na true_pct
1    A  true false  true           2      4     0.50
2    B        true false false     1      4     0.25
3    C false  true  true false     2      4     0.50
```

Please share better solutions, thanks.

**Update:** for the following dataset, the code seems doesn't return the correct outcomes:

```
df <- structure(list(test = c("A", "B", "C"), `2018` = c("true", NA, NA
), `2019` = c("true", "", "false"), `2020` = c("false", "true", 
                                               "true"), `2021` = c("true", "false", "true"), `2022` = c("", 
                                                                                                        "false", "false")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
                                                                                                        ))

tmp <- df[-1]
df$true_pct <- rowSums(tmp == "true")/rowSums(tmp != "" & !is.na(tmp))
df
```

Or:

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[-1] == "true")
df$not_na <- rowSums(sapply(df[, 2:6], function(x){x %in% c("true", "false")}))
df$true_pct <- df$count/df$not_na
df
```

Generate same result:

```
  test 2018  2019  2020  2021  2022 true_pct
1    A true  true false  true           0.75
2    B <NA>        true false false       NA
3    C <NA> false  true  true false       NA
```

Comment: Try this: `df$not_na <- rowSums(sapply(df[, 2:5], function(x){x %in% c("true", "false")}))`

Comment: Could u please test my edited data? I tested, it did't generate what I need. @Marta

Comment: Problem found, I need to add `na.rm=TRUE` to `rowSums()` when dataframe has `NA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
#To select only required columns
tmp <- df[-1]
#Total true values divided by total values which are not `NA` or empty.
df$true_pct <- rowSums(tmp == "true")/rowSums(tmp != "" & !is.na(tmp))
df

#  test  2019  2020  2021  2022  true_pct
#1    A  true false  true       0.6666667
#2    B        true false false 0.3333333
#3    C false  true  true false 0.5000000
```

Comment: For one more question, is it possible to embedded your code to `pipe`?

Comment: You may use `df %>% mutate(true_pct = rowSums(.[-1] == "true")/rowSums(.[-1] != "" & !is.na(.[-1])))` for pipes.

Comment: I'm confused, the code not working out with my real data, I added part of `str(df)` in the end of question, could u please take a look, why it's not working?  I don't tell any difference.

Comment: I think we may need to use `rowSums(tmp != "" | !is.na(tmp))` rather than `rowSums(tmp != "" & !is.na(tmp))`, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

How about this with `rowSums` and `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
df$true_pct <- rowSums(df[-1] == "true", na.rm = TRUE)/rowSums(df[-1] != "" & !is.na(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

or this `dplyr`solution with `apply`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
    df %>%
      mutate(true_pct = apply(.[-1], 1, paste, collapse = " "),
             true_pct = str_count(true_pct, "true")/str_count(true_pct, "true|false"))
  test 2018  2019  2020  2021  2022  true_pct
1    A true  true false  true       0.7500000
2    B <NA>        true false false 0.3333333
3    C <NA> false  true  true false 0.5000000
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(test = c("A", "B", "C"), `2018` = c("true", NA, NA
), `2019` = c("true", "", "false"), `2020` = c("false", "true", 
                                               "true"), `2021` = c("true", "false", "true"), `2022` = c("", 
                                                                                                        "false", "false")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
                                                                                                        ))
```

Comment: Brilliant alternative answer, thanks for sharing.